# Saving security camera stream

Tags: mysql, camera, ffmpeg

I've an axis M1011 camera and i want to continuosly save the flow of the camera and divide it in multiple file? 
Than register it to a database mysql (i think only the information of the file). 
How it is possible to do it? 
I saw ffmpeg but i think i would lose some frame between the various connection.

Comment: Interesting question, but possibly overly broad in scope.

Comment: To what end? Why do you need every frame? What information do you need to "register" in the database? Neither what you want nor why you want it is clear here.

Comment: My idea is to store the the streaming video of the camera in a video. than store the path of the file in a database mysql. The problem is to create the video file in a safe way, without loosing lot of seconds of video recording. Why? becouse it's a security camera and maybe i will need those seconds.

Comment: If you want to capture data from a security camera then why not just use some of the off-the-shelf motion detection stuff (zoneminder, motion etc)?

Answer (score 0):

One simple script is this: this would save a video every minute, the fps = 1. 
The video are saved in the directory in year/month/day/hour/... With a path created as it is, i don't know if it is useful to store the path in the database.

```
b=.avi;
while true; do
    path=`date +%Y/%m/%d/%k/`;
    file=`date +%k:%M-%d_%m_%Y`;
    mkdir -p $path;
    e=$file$b;
    echo $e;
    ffmpeg -r 1 -t "00:01:00" -f mjpeg -i  http://address/mjpg/video.mjpg?         streamprofile=lowprofile $path$e &
    sleep 60;
    i=`expr $i + 1`;
done
```